# Set a boolean to inactive in arraylist for names which i choose and then store them in another array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, store

ill try to explain the code short.. I have an arraylist containing members from a .txt file. In this file i first set all members to being active "true" with a boolean. What i want to do it to using a method taking in a string with a name ( the name of the person in the .txt file i want to set to inacive) Set that person to inactive (false) and then store that person in another array and possibly remove him from the active list so that it dosent contain inactive members.

This is how i started;

```
public static void inActivateName(ArrayList<Member> register, String name) {
    String s = "";
    int counter = 0;
    for(Member m : register) {
        if(m.getFullName().equals(name)) {
            s += (m) + "\n" ;
            counter++;
        }
    } 
    if(counter < 2) {
        System.out.println("Found the name " + name);
        System.out.println("Do you really want to inactivate" + name + " ? " + " (Y/N) ");
        svar = lasaIn.nextLine();
    } else if(svar.equals("Y")) {
            // Inacivate member ? ? ? 
    } else if(svar.equals("N")) {
        System.out.println("Returning to the main menu");
        Menu.mainMenu();    
    }  else {
    System.out.println("Found the name " + name + " " + counter + " times");
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println("Which member do you want to inactivate? (choose by id) ");
    // inActivateId(?) not the problem 
    }
}
```

In my Member class ( another file) i have a method setting all the current "members" to false using ;

```
public boolean getIsActive() {
    return isActive;
}
```

and a constructor doing:  isActive = true;

I really have no clue on how to solve this problem and any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I hope the below solution should work out for you.

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        ArrayList<String> active=new ArrayList<String>();
        active.add("person1");
        active.add("person2");
        active.add("person3");
        ArrayList<String> inactive=new ArrayList<String>();
        deactive("person2",active,inactive);
        System.out.println(active);
        System.out.println(inactive);

     }
     public static void deactive(String person, ArrayList active, ArrayList inactive)
     {
     if(active.contains(person))
     {
        active.remove(person);
        inactive.add(person);
     }
     }
}
```

As you can see, I have two two arraylists active and inactive. Initially all the persons are stored in active arraylist and inactive arraylist is empty. Then I call a function sending the name of the person which I want to remove from the active Array. After calling the function, I have printed both the arraylists. You can see that the particular person is removed from the active arraylist and added to the inactive arraylist.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a temporary object which is set to the current iteration object when the name match is hit. Just list.remove(name) and tempObj.isActive = false in the block you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Make a setter for your member activeness:

```
public void setActive(boolean active) {
  this.active = active;
}

public boolean isActive(){
  return this.active;
}
```

And now a proposal for your code design:

Make a `Map<String, Map<String,Member>>`. Outer map is member groups by name. And inner Map is Member by id. This way you could really simplify your code:

```
public static void inActivateName(Map<String,Map<String, Member>> activeMembers, Map<String,Map<String, Member>> inactiveMembers, String name) {
    Map<String, Member> members = activeMembers.get(name);
    if(members != null)
       System.out.println("Found" + members.size() + " members with the name " + name);
       System.out.println("Do you really want to inactivate" + name + " ? (Y/N)";
       String svar = lasaIn.nextLine();
       if(svar.equals("Y")) {
            System.out.println("Which member do you want to inactivate? (choose by id)");
            svar = lasaIn.nextLine();
            Member member = members.get(svar);
            if(member == null) {
               System.out.println("No such id " + svar);
            } else{
               member.setActive(false);
               System.out.println("Member with name " + name + " and id " + svar + " inactivated");
               activeMembers.remove(svar);
               if(inactiveMembers.get(name) == null){
                  inactiveMembers.put(name, new HashMap<String,Member>());
               }
               inactiveMembers.get(name).put(svar, member);
            }
       }
    } else {
      System.out.println("No such name.");
    }


    System.out.println("Returning to the main menu");
    Menu.mainMenu();
}
```

This example is written to show the concept of how maps might be better to use in your scenario but it is not perfect. If you decide to use this concept then it might be wise to do some refactoring.